# D3 tree positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I want to place the root on top and display only one level children at a time. Once I click the level 1 children , the root and the clicked child along with its children should be displayed.

Below is the code I have tried. The problem Im facing is when i click node1 , I can see node 3 displayed, but when I click on node2 after node 1 I can only see node 5 as a child but not node 4 and 5. Could anyone point me where i am going wrong

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>

     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js?n=1"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js?n=1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <svg width="400px" height="800px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="tran">
  <desc>Example NewCoordSys - New user coordinate system</desc>
  <g class="root">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
    <!-- Draw the axes of the original coordinate system -->
    <line x1="0" y1="1.5" x2="400" y2="1.5" />
    <line x1="1.5" y1="0" x2="1.5" y2="150" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <text x="30" y="30" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" >
     Level root
    </text>
  </g>
  </g>
  <!-- Establish a new coordinate system, which is
       shifted (i.e., translated) from the initial coordinate
       system by 50 user units along each axis. -->
  <g transform="translate(0,200)" class="level1">
    <g fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" >
      <!-- Draw lines of length 50 user units along 
           the axes of the new coordinate system -->
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="red" />
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="300" />
    </g>
    <text x="30" y="30" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" >
      Level 1
    </text>
  </g>

   <g transform="translate(0,500)" class="level2">
    <g fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" >
      <!-- Draw lines of length 50 user units along 
           the axes of the new coordinate system -->
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="blue" />
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="250" />
    </g>
    <text x="30" y="30" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" >
      Level 2
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
    <script>

    nodes = [ {"id":0, "start":10 , "stop":100, "total":90, "prev":[], "next":[1,2]},
              {"id":1, "start":30 , "stop":50, "total":20, "prev":[0], "next":[3]},
              {"id":2, "start":60 , "stop":80, "total":20, "prev":[0], "next":[4,5]},
              {"id":3, "start":90 , "stop":110, "total":20, "prev":[1], "next":[]},
              {"id":4, "start":120 , "stop":150, "total":30, "prev":[2], "next":[]},
              {"id":5, "start":160 , "stop":190, "total":30, "prev":[2], "next":[6]},
              {"id":6, "start":100 , "stop":130, "total":30, "prev":[5], "next":[]}]

    start_pos = 50;

    init();

    function init(){

       data_val = [];

       data_val.push(nodes[0]);

       svg =  d3.select(".root")

       svg.selectAll("rect")
          .data(data_val)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:rect")
       .attr("class","conodes_root")
         .attr("width",function(d){ return d.total;})
         .attr("height","30")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.start;})
         .attr("y",start_pos)
         .style("fill","blue")
         .style("opacity","0.5")
         .on("click",function(d){
             if(d.next.length != 0){
               start_pos = 100;
               child(d.next, start_pos);
             }
           });


        svg.append("svg:g")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(data_val)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:text")
       .attr("class","conodes_root")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.total/2;})
         .attr("y",70)
         .text(function(d){ return d.id + " " + " (" + d.next.length + " ) "; });

    }

    function child(child_arr, start_pos){

       console.log(child_arr);

       child_arr_nodes = [];

       child_arr.forEach(function(d){

            child_arr_nodes.push(nodes[d]);

       })

       console.log(child_arr_nodes);

       svg_l1 =  d3.select(".level1")

       svg_l1.selectAll("rect")
          .data(child_arr_nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:rect")
       .attr("class","conodes_child")
         .attr("width",function(d){ 
          console.log(d);
          return d.total;})
         .attr("height","30")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.start;})
         .attr("y",start_pos)
         .style("fill","blue")
         .style("opacity","0.5")
         .on("click",function(d){
               //if(d.next.length != 0){
               start_pos = 150
               child_l2(d.next, start_pos);
             //}
           })


        /*svg_l1.append("svg:g")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(child_arr_nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:text")
       .attr("class","conodes_child")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.total/2;})
         .attr("y",start_pos)
         .text(function(d){ return d.id + " " + " (" + d.next.length + " ) "; });*/



    }

    function child_l2(child_arr, start_pos){

       console.log(child_arr);

       child_arr_nodes = [];

       child_arr.forEach(function(d){
            child_arr_nodes.push(nodes[d]);
       })

       console.log(child_arr_nodes);

       svg_l2 =  d3.select(".level2")

       svg_l2.selectAll("rect")
          .data(child_arr_nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:rect")
       .attr("class", function(d){ return "child" + d.id;})
         .attr("width",function(d){ 
          console.log(d);
          return d.total;})
         .attr("height","30")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.start;})
         .attr("y",start_pos)
         .style("fill","blue")
         .style("opacity","0.5")
         /*.on("click",function(d){
               //if(d.next.length != 0){
               start_pos = 150
               child_l2(d.next, start_pos);
             //}
           })*/


        /*svg_l1.append("svg:g")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(child_arr_nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:text")
       .attr("class","conodes_child")
         .attr("x",function(d){ return d.total/2;})
         .attr("y",start_pos)
         .text(function(d){ return d.id + " " + " (" + d.next.length + " ) "; });*/

    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. What part are you struggling with? Did you start from a specific example?

Comment: I dint start with any example but my idea is to display child items in different groups but unable to display all the child items of each parent level. I mean if there are 2 nodes in level 1 and say node1 has child3 and node2 has child4 and child5 , i want to display all three children in a group called level2 but on click of node1 it shows child3 and after that if i click on node2 now it should show child4 and child5..but it shows child5 only ..so i want to know where is the logic failing in the code..

Comment: The structure you're describing doesn't sound like a tree to me.